# Implementing soft delete with spring data and hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

What is the best way to implement soft delete  in spring data and on delete that should also trigger hibernate events

Comment: Question is too broad, This might help you out https://levelup.gitconnected.com/spring-boot-soft-delete-functionality-with-hibernate-f5ee8c24c99f

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on [how to implement soft deletes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-crud) in the Hibernate ORM documentation:

```
@SQLDelete(
    sql = "UPDATE person SET valid = false WHERE id = ? "
)
public static class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```